# How to know an exact location of NullReferenceException

Tags: c#

I am trying to a catch nullreference exception but I want to know the exact location (at which point or line I am getting that exception). I have one class named `Employee` and it has two properties: `_Id` and `_Name`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Employee empobj = new Employee();

    try
    {
        empobj = null;
        //empobj._Id = empobj._Id.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(empobj._Id);
        Console.WriteLine(empobj._Name);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception caught: {0}", e.InnerException);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Debugger in your project.

Comment: Maybe stacktrace will help?

Comment: Why do you want to know the exact location?

Comment: add many try catch blocks?

Comment: I just wanted to know that due to which object I am getting that exception.

Comment: Print `e` instead of `e.InnerException`, to see the exception's stack trace. It should tell you the line where the exception occurred.

Comment: @user3351581 Stacktrace should give all the details you need including the code line numbers.

Comment: Hi Sergey.. Could you please more elaborate on stacktrace?

Answer (score 3):

In visual studio go to Debug->Exceptions menu.

[image: Exceptions dialog]

Then select "Common Language Runtime Exceptions", Check the Thrown checkbox. This will break the execution when exception is thrown. You can find the breaked line is where exceptio is thrown.

In case of `NullReferenceException` you won't get much help about stacktrace, but this way you can get the cause easily.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the stack trace and it will have a break down of the execution tree, stating line numbers along with function names and so on. You can do this by debugging, outputting your exception stack trace to some medium, or by removing the try/catch and letting the exception halt execution of your application.

The key would be, though, to work around the exception so that it doesn't happen, if it's *not* an exceptional circumstance (i.e. if you expect that this is a scenario that could very well happen); so if your application can check, such as

```
if (thing != null) {
  var id = thing.Id;
  if (id != null) {
    var idText = id.ToString();
    // and so on
  }
} else {

}
```

Where in the else, you either continue a different route, let the user retry or whatever.

If it is a truly exceptional circumstance (i.e. things should never be null) and the app can't do anything if it is, then let the exception happen, it breaks the application.

Answer (score 2):

Stack trace is the way to go, but the exception is coming from the following lines:

```
Console.WriteLine(empobj._Id);
Console.WriteLine(empobj._Name);
```

You are setting the employee object to null

```
empobj = null;
```

and then trying to access member variables from that class, which will no longer have values for these variables