# Copy list of of objects to another list of another objects within another object

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

My method returns a response object which contains a list of objects.

```
public class GetAccountsListResponse
{
    public List<AccountsList> Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class AccountsList
{
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }

}
```

I tried something like this, but im getting null refernce exception :

```
public GetAccountsListResponse GetAccountsList()
    {

        AccountRepository objRepo = new AccountRepository();
        GetAccountsListResponse res = new GetAccountsListResponse();

        List<Account> lstAccnts = new List<Account>();
        lstAccnts = objRepo.GetAccountsFromRepo();

        foreach (var item in lstAccnts)
        {
            res.Accounts = new List<AccountsList>();
            res.Accounts.ForEach(c => c.AccountId = item.AccountId);    

        }

        return res;
    }
```

Please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: in  which line you are getting this

Comment: Looks like lstAccnts *might* be coming back null from the call `objRepo.GetAccountsFromRepo()`.

Comment: `res.Accounts = new List<AccountsList>(); res.Accounts.ForEach(c => c.AccountId = item.AccountId);` These two lines doesn't makes sense. you create `new List<>` and `ForEach` ? It will always have zero elements

Comment: @K.B im getting error in  res.Accounts.ForEach(c => c.AccountId = item.AccountId);

Comment: @Baldrick no it is returning list of accounts

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel can u pls help me fix the issue, if u have understood the question?

Comment: Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146277/how-to-know-an-exact-location-of-nullreferenceexception/22146474#22146474) to track where the null reference exception happens. Then you can fix it by checking for null or instantiating new object.

Comment: You start the confusion by naming an AccountItem an AccountList. And then there is your are creating (empty) lists everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's obvious as you are only creating a new list with no object instantiated at all 
try something like this

```
    res.Accounts = new List<AccountsList>();
    foreach (var item in lstAccnts)
    {

        res.Accounts.Add( new AccountsList(){AccountId =item.AccountId});    

    }
```

Comment: This also doesn't makes sense

Comment: answer  edited take a look now why not this will create a new list from  the lstAccnts and  add items to res.Accounts